# Time to accept answer

Tags: discussion

Normally, when I have asked questions, I am able to select the answer as soon as someone posts it. However, recently, I asked a question and when I went to select the answer it told me I could accept in 5 minutes.

Looking around I have seen a couple comments about being able to select the answer in a couple days.

Just out of curiosity, why is there a time till accept feature? What purpose does it serve?

And second, what is the algorithm that decides how long that time to accept is?

Not a duplicate mainly because I want to know why there are different time periods.
(edit: Turns out that there is a general time till accept, than an extended time till accept if its your own answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is there a time till accept feature? What purpose does it serve?

Once a question has an accepted answer, chances of getting more answers drop (partially do to the incentive of the accept reputation being gone).

This can be harmful to the question OP, in that the first answer may be incorrect, incomplete or even actively harmful. And "competing" or better/different answer may very well not be forthcoming.

There is no harm in waiting for a while before accepting. I routinely waited for a couple of days on questions before selecting an accepted answer, even if I got a great on off the bat.

> what is the algorithm that decides how long that time to accept is?

Nothing special, just the amount of time since the question was posted.

This is 15 minutes except for self answers, which require 2 days (48 hours).

For details, see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: so theres no way for the time to be extended past 15 minutes?

Comment: @Humdinger - you can post a feature request, but you will need to show a good reason for that to be accepted.

Comment: @Humdinger: Post your own answer, then you can't accept it for 2 days!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, That answers my question!

Comment: @Humdinger: I really don't see the point of even keeping this question in existence since, as you point out, it's already been answered elsewhere, and the timings are available on another answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok thats a good point.